# Where can i find a texture like this? (Silky thick smoke)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, texture

This is my first post so please be kind, however do tell me if i do something wrong :). My Question:

I've been looking for this texture (the one pictured below) for ages and i just can not find out what is called or where i can get it. Can someone help please?

Thank you in advanced :)

[image: I just want to find the purple silk, smoke texture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight I'd say that's coloured dye or ink in water rather than smoke. Like this one:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdryq.png)

Some Google search results confirm this:

[Blue](https://goo.gl/images/wdHN62)

[Red](https://goo.gl/images/QKqBPS)

[Multicolour](https://goo.gl/images/tfihxB)

[Another multicolour](https://goo.gl/images/HQ81yU)

Comment: thank you so much! It crossed my mind that it could be that but I didn't look into it. Thank you again :)

Comment: No problem, that's what we're here for